# Cocos2d-x Sprite Inheritance class Error

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm making a spacewar game.
I finished adding enemies, shooting bullets, detecting collisions.
The next step is adding HP for each object.

I created class which inherits Sprite

```
class Target : public cocos2d::Sprite
{
public:
    int hp = -1;
};
```

I checked whether HP changes well or not by adding 3 code lines below.

```
Target *target = new Target();
target->hp = 1;
CCLog("hp: %d", target->hp);
```

result:
hp: 1

The problem is, after returning Sprite by this line,

```
target = (Target*)Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("enemy1.png");

CCLog("hp: %d", target->hp);
```

the result is
hp: -33686019

In addition, I'm not able to change the HP variable. When I change it, the debugger stops at "target->hp = 1;".

Comment: Dude you have created object of type Sprite and then casting it to Target. I think you should first learn some OOP basics.

Comment: read this link to create custom sprite http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_To_Subclass_Sprite_And_Add_Event_Listeners

Comment: You are doing in wrong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. First - you can't initialise int in .h file. Second - don't use new directly - it'll easily cause memory leaks if not handled properly, instead use cocos2d-x pattern.

I'll do it like this:

.h file:

```
#ifndef __Sample__Target__
#define __Sample__Target__

#include "cocos2d.h"

USING_NS_CC;

class Target : public Sprite
{
public:
    static Target* create(const std::string& filename);
    int hp;
};

#endif
```

.cpp file:

```
#include "Target.h"

Target* Target::create(const std::string& filename) {
    auto ret = new (std::nothrow) Target;
    if(ret && ret->initWithFile(filename)) {
        ret->autorelease();
        ret->hp = 1; //declare here or in init
        return ret;
    }
    CC_SAFE_RELEASE(ret);
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Deadline was Dec 12, I solved it by using tags. But I really wondered how to do it with Target class, so I applied your code to mine just before, it works really fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
target = Target::createWithSpriteFrameName("enemy1.png");
```

Comment: Actually I tried it at first, before the code in my question. But didn't work T.T